# Sorting dataframe to achieve desired form

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

Good morning everyone

I have the following example:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 5))
colnames(data) = paste("art_", 1:5, sep = "")
rownames(data) = paste("use_", 1:3, sep = "")
data["use_1",c("art_1","art_2","art_3")] = 1
data["use_2",c("art_2","art_3")] = 1
data["use_3",c("art_1","art_2","art_3","art_4","art_5")] = 1

#This is how the table looks like:
      art_1 art_2 art_3 art_4 art_5
use_1     1     1     1     0     0
use_2     0     1     1     0     0
use_3     1     1     1     1     1
```

Now i want to rearrange or sort the rows and columns so that all entries with 1 are grouped in the left upper corner.
Here is how it should look like after the rearrangement:

```
      art_2 art_3 art_1 art_4 art_5
use_3     1     1     1     1     1
use_1     1     1     1     0     0
use_2     1     1     0     0     0
```

Thank you very much for any kind of hints and help.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `apply`, sort by row (`MARGIN = 1`) and then by column (`MARGIN = 2`):

```r
data[] <- t(apply(data, 1, sort, decreasing = T))
data[] <- apply(data, 2, sort, decreasing = T)

      art_1 art_2 art_3 art_4 art_5
use_1     1     1     1     1     1
use_2     1     1     1     0     0
use_3     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: I 'd suggest `sapply()` for the column operation

Comment: I have a question about the row- and colnames. This information is lost right? Or is there a way to order the sequence of the entries and change the colnames and rownames accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
data[order(rowSums(data), decreasing=TRUE), order(colSums(data), decreasing=TRUE)]
```

Output:

```
      art_2 art_3 art_1 art_4 art_5
use_3     1     1     1     1     1
use_1     1     1     1     0     0
use_2     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: OP's expected output is slightly different (see last row); which then should be `data[order(rowSums(data), decreasing=TRUE), order(colSums(data), decreasing=TRUE)]`.

Comment: Thanks to @Maël, I changed the code!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
data[names(sort(apply(data, 2, sum), decreasing = T))]

#>       art_2 art_3 art_1 art_4 art_5
#> use_1     1     1     1     0     0
#> use_2     1     1     0     0     0
#> use_3     1     1     1     1     1
```